# Java GUI input text box

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm designing a program simulating a vending machine. You know how vending machines have that one large text box that displays whatever messages you need to know...that's what I want to do. So basically, if the user clicks a button and if the item is out of store, expired, they don't have enough credit, whatever, the message should be displayed in this box.

Then, after a second or 2, return to displaying how much money the user put into the machine. I also want to make the box so that, well theres a button next to the text box to click to insert money. When they click that, I want to make the text box editable, they then enter the amount of money they want to enter, then press insert again, and the money is inserted. The text box becomes uneditable again, and displays the credit they have in the machine.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to do this?

I also was wondering how I could implement the delay before getting rid of the message and returning to displaying the credit in the machine. Thank you.

Comment: sunday afternoons seem to be homework time

Comment: Use a `JTextField`, ask a specific question when you strike a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew Thompson says, you would use a JTextField. Set the desired text using the setText() method and you could then use a sleep function (usleep() I think should work for your application) and then set the text again back to the Dollar value.

Edit: didn't see the last half. To enable and disable the textfield entirely, use setEnabled(true/false), to stop it from being editable, use setEditable(true/false)

Also, just thinking, you could get the current date in a timestamp format and then enter a loop where you continually get the timestamp and compare it to the first one. If the desired difference is reached then exit the loop and update the textfield. Have a look at the Java doc for Date ;)